# Sort a HTML Table Column that Contains SQL Data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating a simple transactions report page that takes inputted database data and displays it on an HTML table. I want to be able to sort each column on the client side in asc/desc order when the table header is clicked upon, but I can't get my functions to work.

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include 'head.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ach";


$result = $mysqli->query($sql);


echo "<div class='w3-row-padding w3-margin'>";
if ($result->num_rows) {
    echo "<table class='w3-table-all'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=submittedDate'>Submitted Date</a></th>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=accountNumber'>Chief Account Number</a></th>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=accountHolderName'>Account Holder</a></th>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=achAccountType'>Account Type</a></th>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=transferType'>Transfer Type</a></th>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=recurringMonthlyTransferDate'>Transfer Date</a></th>
            <th><a href='transactions.php?sort=status'>Status</a></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tbody><tr><td>".$row["submitDate"]."</td><td>".$row["accountNumber"]."</td><td>".$row["accountHolderName"]."</td><td>".$row["achAccountType"]."</td><td>".$row["transferType"]."</td><td>".$row["recurringMonthlyTransferDate"]."</td><td>".$row["status"]."</td><td><a href=review.php?ID=" . $row["id"] . ">Review</a></td></tr></tbody>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "</div>";

if ($_GET['sort'] == 'submittedDate')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY `ach`.`submitDate` ASC ";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'accountNumber')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY accountNumber";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'accountHolderName ')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY accountHolderName ASC";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'achAccountType')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY achAccountType";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'transferType')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY transferType";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'recurringMonthlyTransferDate')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY recurringMonthlyTransferDate";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'status')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY status";
}

$mysqli->close();

include 'foot.php';
?>
```

Comment: I understand that you need to do this on your own.. But please take a look at [Bootstrap Datatable](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) which could help you.. Bootstrap datatable has inbuilt functions to  sort,search, filter etc...but only at the client side...

Comment: You can use data table if want to sort at client end.

Comment: I tried using the datatable but it wasn't working.

Comment: put <tbody> </tbody> outside the while. you table is having as many tbody tags as there are many rows

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must add your sorting statements BEFORE you execute the query. Query is executed on this line:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **sort data at server end** you have to use o**rder by clause**. If you want **jquery to sort** at client end you can use [Data tables](https://datatables.net/)

Also put `<tbody> </tbody>` outside the while. your table is having many `tbody` tags as there are many rows.

```
   $sort = "";
    if(isset($_GET["sort"])) {
        $sort = $_GET["sort"];
        //validate that it is real column name so that you will not get any error
        if(!in_array($sort, array("submittedDate", "accountNumber", "accountHolderName", "achAccountType", "transferType", "recurringMonthlyTransferDate", "status"))) {
            $sort = "";
        }
        if($sort !="") {
            $sort = " order by ".$sort." ASC";
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ach".$sort;
```